# Incomplete shape error when try to export inference in tensor flow object detection api although overwrite input_shape parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I retrained ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29 from Tensorflow detection model zoo by following the procedures defined in Tensorflow Object Detection API using my own dataset. When I try to export the model by

python object_detection/export_inference_graph.py     --input_type=image_tensor     --pipeline_config_path=.../pipeline.config     --trained_checkpoint_prefix=.../model.ckpt-200000     --output_directory=.../export-model-200000 --input_shape=1,300,300,3

it says "20 ops no flops stats due to incomplete shapes." although I overwrite input_shape with 1,300,300,3.

How can I overcome this problem?

My final goal is to convert this model into IR representation, in which I got problems related to shape inference during model conversion whereas I have no problem with converting the original model, which I used for transfer learning, into IR.

Thanks